# How to get single item from json result when using Twitter API in python?

Tags: python, json, twitter, key

I am using the Twitter API. When I print the 'Tweets' the result is a lot of text with all the information of the tweet. However, I am only interested in getting the `'text'`. I am pretty sure the result I am getting in in a JSON format. So can anyone tell me how to extract a single key from this?

Code:

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret_key)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

public_tweets = api.home_timeline()

for tweet in public_tweets:
    print(tweet)
```

The result I am getting looks like:

```
Status(_api=<tweepy.api.API object at 0x000002269C3B8390>, _json={'created_at': 'Tue Nov 03 11:02:03 +0000 2020', 'id': 1323581198132748288, 'id_str': '1323581198132748288', 'text': 'Prachtig nieuw station. - Anoniem', 'truncated': False, 'entities': {'hashtags': [],
```

From this result I would just like the key `'text'`

Any help is welcome!

Comment: Have you tried `print('tweet._json.text')` or `print('tweet.text')`

Comment: Take a look at this [GitHub thread](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/1085).

Comment: @MohammedIsmail Wow. Sometimes the answer is really that simple. It worked. Thank you.